# How do I change how a POST request is saved in my db.json?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, post, server

I've created a fake JSON server using `npm i json-server` in my React application. I've created a `db.json` file and have created the following function to push a new 'task' to the server for persistence:

```
const addTask = async task => {
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/tasks`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(task)
  })

  const data = await res.json()

  setTasks([...tasks, data])
}
```

Now, this is how my db.json is being saved:

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Doctors Appointment",
      "day": "Feb 5th at 2:30PM",
      "reminder": true
    },
    {
      "text": "SWE Interview",
      "day": "May 9th at 9:30AM",
      "reminder": false,
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "text": "School Meeting",
      "day": "Feb 11th at 5:30PM",
      "reminder": false,
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

id:1 has been manually entered and id:2 and id:3 have been POST'd in using the UI. How can I make it so that they follow the same pattern of arrangement as id:1 i.e. id, text, day then reminder?

Answer (score 1):

Order of keys in JSON should not have any affect on the data. If you still need the object to be in a specific order, I would write custom function to stringify the JSON. Here's the code I came up with:

```js
function stringifyTask(task) {
    return `{
    "id": ${task.id},
    "text": "${task.text}",
    "day": "${task.day}",
    "reminder": ${task.reminder}
}`
}
```

Comment: Where would this function go exactly? Will it be within the await fetch block?

Comment: This function would be separate from your addTask function, so probably before your first line. You would call this function instead of JSON.stringify with the same parameters